# MySql Select Query Optimisation

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization

I recently came across a query in one of our office discussions,

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.date AS date_filter, 
        (SELECT t2.column_x 
         FROM table_2 t2 
         WHERE t2.date = date_filter LIMIT 1
        ) AS column_x 
FROM table_1 t1 
WHERE t1.category_id = 10 
ORDER BY t1.date 
LIMIT 10;
```

The sub-query returns a column value from a second table that matches the date from the first table.
This query is not running at an optimised speed, can you guys pass me what are the ways to improvise the performance ?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It would help to have `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Indexes needed:

```
t1: INDEX(category_id, date)
t2: INDEX(date)
```

The subquery does not make sense without an `ORDER BY` -- which "1" row do you want?